# Classification by neural network from a feature in a piecewise manner

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Suppose I wish to predict a binary class {0, 1}. One of the feature x is a real. Can a neural network produce a model such that the model predicts class 1 if a < x < b (given a, b are reals such that a < b), and predict class 0 otherwise?

In general, if we want x to predict class 1 if x is in (a1, b1) union (a2, b2) union (a3, b3) ...
where a1 < b1 < a2 < b2 < a3 < b3..., is it possible to achieve this by neural network? (there will be no limit  on the number of neurons/layers used)

Edit: can you also give a numerical example as illustration?

Comment: Is a and b known? if so why would you want a neural network to classify when you already know how it should be classified?

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro they are not known. I just know they exist.

Comment: Ok so it makes sense in a way. but it seems that what you want is something more interpretable than neural networks. Did you searched for fuzzy logic already? If you still want to stick with neural networks there is also one thing called neuro-fuzzy systems which takes advantages of both neural networks and fuzzy logic

Comment: A decision tree (e.g., [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm)) can solve this problem and would probably be a better classifier than an ANN, particularly if the number of `(a, b)` pairs is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn `a < x < b` with a `1x2x1` network (one neuron in the input layer, two neurons in a hidden layer, and a single neuron in the output layer). One of the hidden layer neurons represents `a < x` and the other represents `x < b`. The output neuron is a logical `OR` of the hidden layer neurons.

To generalize this to `N` pairs of `(a, b)` values, you would want at least `2 * N` neurons in the hidden layer. It could be done with fewer hidden layer neurons (e.g., if some of the `a` or `b` values are not unique) but in practice, it is better to use a number greater than `2 * N` and allow the unnecessary weight to tend toward zero during the learning process.

You could also learn the more general case using multiple hidden layers but whether or not that is better than a single hidden layer will likely depend on how the `(a, b)` pairs are distributed.

Comment: very detailed and clear answer. thank you very much!